# can't get the empty cell only colored

Tags: c#, devexpress

I would like by that code to color only the empty cells.
But i'm getting all the cells colored.
Can anybody tell me where's my fault..

```
private void gridView3_RowCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
        GridView View = sender as GridView;
        if(e.Column.FieldName == "First Name") 
        {
            string category = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["First Name"]);
            if(category != "") 
            {   
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well for one thing the condition is wrong:

```
if (category != "")
```

You are filtering so that the cells that are NOT empty get colored. So replace that with a `String.IsNullOrEmpty(category)` first.

Next, because you are using DevExpress controls, maybe you could use the built in Conditional Formatting: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument759

Something like this maybe:

```
StyleFormatCondition condition1 = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition();
condition1.Appearance.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
condition1.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;
condition1.Condition = FormatConditionEnum.Expression;
condition1.Expression = "[First Name] == ''";
gridView1.FormatConditions.Add(condition1);
```

Comment: The problem is that i can't use "Appearance"
'DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition' does not contain a definition for 'Appearance'

Is it because I am using Visual studio 2003 ?

Comment: @Nejthe - No, it has nothing to do with that. Either you have an older version of DevExpress controls. Either way, if you have issues with their controls, ask on their support forum.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is coloring non-empty cells (check your condition `if(category != "")`)

The following works for me:

```
private void gridView3_RowCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    GridView View = sender as GridView;
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "First Name" &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, e.Column)))
    {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much..
my problem here is that I am getting this error...

'DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition' does not contain a definition for 'Appearance'.. Is it because I'm using visual studio 2003 ?